# Increasing the Accuracy of NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following graph:

[image]

Based on theoretical reasons, I expect the the global maximum of the graph to be in the range $[0, 1)$. The graph seems to suggest that is the case. When I run,

```
NMaximize[{f[α, χ, 1], 0 <= α <= 2 π, 
 0 <= χ <= π}, {{α, 1, 2}, {χ, 1, 2}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 5],
```

I get

`-0.0138260893013031`

as my global maximum, which is significantly different from zero.

How can I increase the working accuracy/power/precision of the `NMaximize` command to (hopefully) obtain the desired resul -- $0$ in this case.

Comment: Hard to say without the function.

Comment: @Feyre Would you like me to provide all the code for the function? With the details in the preamble, the code is pretty long.

Comment: Can't you just state what the function is? No need to have others calculate it. I.e what you get when you query `f[α, χ, 1]`.

Comment: @Feyre I don't the last phrase. Also, when I run `NMaximize[{f[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 1], 0 <= \[Alpha] <= 2 \[Pi], 
  0 <= \[Chi] <= \[Pi]}, {{\[Alpha], 3, 6}, {\[Chi], 1, 2}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 50]`, I get the `NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.` and `{0, {\[Alpha] -> 
   6.2831852522734397650776946727655321337136931922922, \[Chi] -> 
   1.5707963470315534833112907836556392827297652851478}}`. When I evaluate `f` at the said points, I get `-1.2160785156645204`*^-9`. Good enough?

Comment: `MaxIterations->1000`?

Comment: @Feyre What? I don't get you.

Comment: `NMaximize[{f[α, χ, 1], 0 <= α <= 2 π, 
 0 <= χ <= π}, {{α, 1, 2}, {χ, 1, 2}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision,MaxIterations->1000]`
If that doesn't work, I'd have to know the code of `f` to say anything else.

Comment: @Feyre Yes, this did the trick as well -- along with my running `NMaximize` with `WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 50`.

Answer (score 6):

Families of functions follow Tolstoy's dictum: "All happy families are alike. All unhappy families are unhappy in their own way."

Functions from happy families cheerfully yield their optima without the user having look up method options in the docs.  When this does not happen, you suspect your function is from an unhappy family and wonder what is the particular problem with this function.  What method or strategy would be appropriate to apply to this problem?  ***It's hard to say, if you do not know what the function is,*** which is the situation the rest of here are in, since the OP does not post the function.

Nonetheless, here are some possibilities...

### There is no error.

If you look at the graph, the maximum looks like it should be around

```
-0.0138260893013031
```

which is what the OP reports was the answer.  It is no way suggests to me that the answer should lie in the interval $[0,1)$ mentioned by the OP.  Further, the plot looks like a function from a fairly happy family.  Having a few local maxima might fool `FindMaximum[]`, but I doubt `NMaximize` failed.  Most likely, the OP made a mistake.

But there's no way to check this, since the OP did not share the function.

### If you can plot the function, use the plot.

It's a fairly simple looking plot, and just by looking one might come up with up to four likely starting points near local maxima.  It may be clear that some peaks are not the global maximum and can be ignored.  One can easily choose a point `{α0, χ0}` near each local maximum and feed it to `FindMaximum`:

```
FindMaximum[{f[α, χ, 1], 0 <= α <= 2 π, 0 <= χ <= π}, {{α, α0}, {χ, χ0}}]
```

From the results you get, it's not hard to choose the maximum.

This is a brute-force approach.  For a good (i.e. accurate) plot that has too many maxima to read by eye, one can use `Cases[]` to get the computed points from the plot. The points with the greatest z-coordinates can be used as starting points.  This is shown in another Q&A that I cannot find.

### Try to avoid the brute-force approach

The brute-force approach is not pretty.  There are reasons the function's family is unhappy, and if it were to submit to analysis one might find them out.  A thorough analysis of the function needs to be complemented by delving into the docs and getting a thorough understanding of the suboptions of all the optimization methods available in *Mathematica*.  While this can take a lot of time, compared to just getting the answer and moving on, the understanding one obtains can be quite beautiful, with time spent enjoyably in the pursuit of knowledge.

Whether you think I'm speaking facetiously depends on your point of view.  Personally, I'm more interested in mathematics than whether `-0.0138260893013031` is correct or not.  Others to whom answers have significance for their own projects are often more interested in their projects.  They might want to take a few minutes to do the brute-force method, instead of spending hours finding a way that takes only a second or two.  (The choice also depends on whether what you learn will be, or might be, useful in the future.)

Comment: One might consider using a combination of `PeakDetect[]` and `FindMaximum[]` for suitable cases.

Comment: @Michael E2 Say you have a variable, `plot`, equated to the 3D plot. What would be the statement using `Cases` to extract the maximum `z` values? Thank you.

Comment: @JackLaVigne `pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity]` will get you the {x,y,z} points. `SortBy[pts, Last]` will put them in increasing order by function value. Or use `maxpts = Select[pts, Last[#] > critval &]` for a suitable critical value. Since the max may not be a sample point, use `MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{critval}}` to visually check that you get all of the high peaks. `ListPlot[FindClusters@maxpts[[All, ;; 2]], GridLines -> Automatic]` shows whether `FindClusters` separates them. Etc., but stop when you can pick starting points for `FindMinimum`.